# Huge difference of download speeds between different sites

Tags: download, youtube

I have a local Internet provider, the normal download speed which I get is around 100-150 kbps but on downloading YouTube Videos via www.save-video.com(change youtube to youmagictube) or TubeMate on mobile device I get down speed of 2-2.5 mbps, I can't understand what is happening here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, you are downloading some frequent content that is stored in the provider's cache.